# why is sigma field important when a sample space is uncountable?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, elementary-set-theory

I am a undergraduate student studying mathematical statistics. I am learning about sigma field and I dont understand why sigma field is so important when sample space is uncountable. Can anyone tell me what properties of sigma field make sigma field so important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Cantor's power theorem, all the subsets of an uncountable set are of infinity $\aleph_2$, one higher than the infinity of an uncountable set $\aleph_1$ (assuming Continuum Hypothesis and Generalized Continuum Hypothesis be true). Most of sets in $\aleph_2$ are beyond the reach of current understanding and out of interest in probability theory. For example, we are only concerned about sets that are Lebesgue measurable in probability theory.

As the result, probability theory mainly studies a sub-class of sets in uncountable sample space known as Borel Sets, which is defined as the smallest $\sigma$ field that contains all the open sets. Borel Sets are Lebesgue measurable and $\sigma$-field consists entirely of Borel Sets. That is why $\sigma$-field is so important.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand why it is so important. But what happens if we take the power set of an uncountable set and define a probability set function on it?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. That actually is the problem of measurablity of $\aleph_2$ sets, which is still open I believe.

Comment: Oh I see. Then is it possible to define a probability function on any sigma field?

Comment: Yes, that is called probability triple.

Comment: I have to correct your set theory: (1) All cardinals greater than $\aleph_0$ are called uncountable, not just $\aleph_1$. (2) The cardinality of the reals is $2^{\aleph_0}$ and there are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ subsets of the reals. These cardinals are *not* provably equal to $\aleph_1$ and $\aleph_2$. The Continuum Hypothesis ($2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$) and the Generalized Continuum Hypothesis ($2^{\aleph_{\alpha}} = \aleph_{\alpha+1}$ for all $\alpha$, so in particular $2^{2^{\aleph_0}} = \aleph_2$) are both independent of ZFC (the usual foundational axioms of mathematics).